# IF function depending on Order Type

Tags: vba, sap-gui

```
   Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")
   Set SapApp = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
End If
If Not IsObject(Connection) Then
   Set Connection = SapApp.Children(0)
End If
If Not IsObject(session) Then
   Set session = Connection.Children(0)
End If
If IsObject(WScript) Then
   WScript.ConnectObject session, "on"
   WScript.ConnectObject SapApp, "on"
End If

Dim SO_ref As String
Dim PO_order As String
Dim ship_cond As String
Dim antal As Integer
Dim i As Integer

antal = Range("F8").Value

Range("E11:E40").Clear

If OPT_Cust1.Value = True Then 
    SO_ref = Range("F2").Value
    PO_order = Range("G2").Value
    ship_cond = Range("H2").Value
    Else
End If

If OPT_Cust2.Value = True Then 
    SO_ref = Range("F3").Value
    PO_order = Range("G3").Value
    ship_cond = Range("H3").Value
End If

If Cust3.Value = True Then 
    SO_ref = Range("F4").Value
    PO_order = Range("G4").Value
    ship_cond = Range("H4").Value
End If

If Cust4.Value = True Then
    SO_ref = Range("F5").Value
    PO_order = Range("G5").Value
    ship_cond = Range("H5").Value
End If

i = 1

Do While i < antal + 1

session.findById("wnd[0]").resizeWorkingPane 160, 38, False
'session.createSession
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "va01"
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtVBAK-AUART").Text = "ABC1" ' Order Type
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtVBAK-VKORG").Text = "xxxx"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtVBAK-VTWEG").Text = "xx"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtVBAK-SPART").Text = "xx"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtVBAK-VKBUR").Text = "xxxx"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtVBAK-VKGRP").Text = "xxx"
```

I got this script for creation of SO "headers". Currently it working fine but I need to add one more customer for which Order type will be different.
Say if the Cust4 is selected then the Order Type should be ABC2 otherwise it should always choose ABC1.

How can this function be added to the script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the next approach, please:

```
Dim boolType2 as Boolean

'...your existing code
If Cust4.Value = True Then
    boolType2 = True
    SO_ref = Range("F5").Value
    PO_order = Range("G5").Value
    ship_cond = Range("H5").Value
End If
'...your existing code
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtVBAK-AUART").Text = _
                    IIf(boolType2 = True, "ABC2", "ABC1")
'...your existing code
```

You can create such boolean variables for many other types, if necessary... `IIf` supports imbricate functions.

Edited:

If your above used controls are check boxes, your code must check if only one of them would be checked. Otherwise, the code will take the values from the last (ticked) one...

If the check boxes are ActiveX type, you can use each of them `Change` event, in order to un-tick the others. If not, try adapting your code in the next way, which will do the same thing, but less elegant (on my taste)...

```
If OPT_Cust1.Value = True Then
    If OPT_Cust2.Value = True Or _
           Cust3.Value = True Or _
           Cust4.Value = True Then _
        MsgBox "Another check box is also ticked!": Exit Sub
        
    SO_ref = Range("F2").Value
    PO_order = Range("G2").Value
    ship_cond = Range("H2").Value
ElseIf OPT_Cust2.Value = True Then
    If Cust3.Value = True Or Cust4.Value = True Then _
        MsgBox "Another check box is also ticked!": Exit Sub
        
    SO_ref = Range("F3").Value
    PO_order = Range("G3").Value
    ship_cond = Range("H3").Value
ElseIf Cust3.Value = True Then
    If Cust4.Value = True Then _
        MsgBox "Cust4 check box is also ticked!": Exit Sub
        
    SO_ref = Range("F4").Value
    PO_order = Range("G4").Value
    ship_cond = Range("H4").Value
ElseIf Cust4.Value = True Then
    boolType2 = True
    SO_ref = Range("F5").Value
    PO_order = Range("G5").Value
    ship_cond = Range("H5").Value
End If
```

Comment: So only add **Dim boolType2 as Boolean** to the group of 5 "Dims" that are in the script and then add **boolType2 = True** to the customer with deviating Order Type or does it need to be added for all customers?

Comment: I am driving now... I missed something. I will correct when I will be home.

Comment: @Adde: I did not remember if the `Cust4` object is an Option Button or a check box. Being an Option Button (probably, all of them in the same group) meaning that only one can be `True`, the answer is: **The variable will be made `True` only in case of the the option button where you want to change something**. You can also use a condition (for instance): `If SO_ref = "x" Then boolType2 = True`. And it will be used only if the condition is `True`.

Comment: It's a check box. All customer options are selectable by check box. There are 4 check boxes.

Comment: Seeing `OPT_Cust1.Value` I thought that all of them will be option/radio buttons... You should stated something about this aspect. If they are check boxes, in order to pass a different string, all your code must be structured in a different way. I will post an updated answer able to solve your question, bun not right now. In less then one hour, I think...

Comment: @Adde: I must understand that **more then one such a check box can be simultaneous checked**. Is that understanding correct? If not and only one of them can be ticked, the code would work as it is... Please, clarify the above issue. I like helping people, but I hate working in vain...

Comment: @Adde: Do you have an answer? Your code cannot work (well) as it is, even without your request, **if you have two such check boxes checked**. The iteration will always use your last check box settings in terms of `SO_ref`, `PO_order`, `ship_cond`  values. You do not say anything, but I would suppose that xx, xxx, xxxx sould be related to above values. Am I wrong?

Comment: Sorry for late reply sir... Only one check box can be checked at the time. I thank you for your help and effort. I had to work with other things on Friday ( could not focus on the script issue)  and then weekend came... Sorry again for late reply..

Comment: @Adde: Then, use my suggestions and it will work as you need. But I would suggest you to also adapt the check boxes `Change` event in order to un-check all the others, If not already did. If they are not Activex Type, to adapt the code you posted (using `ElseIf`). In fact, I will edit my answer and make exact suggestions. But when a code answers your question, we here tick the left code side check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**. In this way, somebody else searching for a similar issue will know that the suggestion worked.

Comment: @Adde: Adapted the code some time before, but forgetting to announce...

Comment: @Adde: Glad I could help! But, in case somebody answer our question, we vote the answer up and more important we tick the left code side check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**. In this way somebody else searching for a similar issue will know that the provided solution works.

Answer (score 0):

Just add variable of "Order Type" and set it for every Cust to your SAP scipt.

```
If Cust4.Value = True Then
    SO_ref = Range("F5").Value
    PO_order = Range("G5").Value
    ship_cond = Range("H5").Value
    Type = "ABCD2"
End If

session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtVBAK-AUART").Text = Type ' Order Type
```

Hope I've helped.
Have a great day :).